# BLAM add-on does not work with Blender 2.79

Tags: add-on, camera, blam

I tried installing both the latest version(v 0.6) and the original one. I downloaded the zip file and then clicked on the install addon from file button. Turns out it does not show in the addons list at all.
   I don't know whats the error. A few days ago there was some kind of numpy error in Animation nodes as well. To fix that, I uninstalled and then reinstalled Blender. When I tried installing BLAM, it still does not work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a bug related to third party software. It needs to be reported to the addon developers.

Comment: @sambler Could be the way they are installing that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm using BLAM on 2.79 without any issues. Try to place blam.py in 2.79/scripts/addons folder manually instead of installing from file.

Comment: the github page says to get the zip and then "decompress the file and locate the actual add-on file src/blam.py" so maybe you could have used an unsupported install method, even if  that usually work for other plugins...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help. Apparently it was not BLAM which had the problem. The problem was with the version of Blender 2.79 that I was using. Apparently it had a lot of bugs that I would keep run into which the previous versions did not have. I downloaded the recent Blender 2.79a (release candidate) which worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

With some plugins, you just need to update the header info.

So unzip it, edit blam.py:line 26 `'blender': (2, 6, 2),`
change it to read `'blender': (2, 7, 9),`
then in Blender:  File > User Prefs > Install from file > blam.py

I haven't tried it, so I can't guarantee your results,
but I believe this'll get you there.

Otherwise, file a bug report at the github page  https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam

Comment: No, I've done this before.  It may have been more than just the version, but it truly was just updating the header and the script worked again.

Comment: And, having just tried it with this plugin, guess what?  Yup, it shoes up under 3D View, just as I said.

Comment: Blender version is the API level that the developer supports for this version of the add on. It can work on later or earlier versions, but it is not guaranteed. Blender devs do not want changes to the API, but this is not always possible. When API has changed and that part of the API is used by the add on, it possible won’t work. The version in the add on is only a filter. So for one case it works, but the other case it won’t. Best thing is to consult the developer of the add on.